# How to test Push Notification is working in my application - in iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, push-notification

I already have asked about [how to test Push notification in iPhone.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361298/how-to-test-push-notification-is-working-in-my-application)
Now I have to test the same in iPad. I found that the tool PushMeBaby does not work in iPad. When I tried to do so it is showing some **Socket error(5)**.
Is there any other tool which helps me to test this? Or Can I fix this error in PushMeBaby tool and make it workable to test the same in iPad?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The iPhone and iPad are exactly the same with respect to push notifications. Also, where do you see "Socket error"?

Comment: Yes, PushMeBaby works quite well for all my devices.

Comment: It is showing on console. The certificate is loaded successfully but when I click on "Push" button, it simply prints "Socket error(5), Log 2".

Comment: It is solved. It was my mistake in providing Device Token - I am adding the answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can use this online tester which supports both Android and iOS. Easy to use simple website http://www.pushtry.com

 1. Select you .p12 file
 2. Enter device token3
 3. Select environment Sandbox or production
 4. Enter message
 5. Send

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am adding this answer just for those who may do the same mistake I have done.
It was giving me error sometime otherwise it was neither giving any error nor any push message is displayed. The Problem was in Device Token. Since I did not copy/paste it but added it manually it was very difficult to find the miss characters. When I replaced it with copy/paste data and re-execute it, it is sending a push message for each click.

Those who believe that PushMeBaby tool is only for iPhone/iPod are wrong (including me before today). It is meant for all the devices. Hats Off to PushMeBaby.