# PushNotification "dryRun" attribute for iOS

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

For Android devices I am using `dryRun` attribute to control message is delivered to device or not, generally I have used this parameter to check the pntoken is invalid or not without sending a sample message to device.

I am searching for same attributes or a way to check whether token is valid, expired or invalid for IOS devices.

Comment: were you able to find an attribute similar to "dryRun" for iOS?

Comment: It is not possible with Apple's technology support team, Apple only focus on money rather than technology.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Dry run option for iOS but you might want to go with message without any alert.

```
{
    "aps": {
      "category": "categoryName"
    }
}
```

With above payload call will go through but nothing should show up on the device.

Comment: let me try, which token should be used pntoken, of voippntoken ??

Comment: You should be using apns token. Actually, it would be a normal APNS call for sending message to an iOS device however, for test/dryRun alert text will not be sent.

Comment: did you try it? The other option is to use APNS sandbox endpoint, which is most common way to doing dry run for iOS push notification.

Answer (score -1):

Based on this [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pushImplGuide.meta/pushImplGuide/pns_test_conn_app_push.htm), to run a quick test of your push notification setup for Apple Push Notification Service (APNS), use the [Send Test Notification page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pushImplGuide.meta/pushImplGuide/connected_app_test_apns.htm).

Here are the steps that you need to do.

1. Enter a connection token string in the Recipient field, OR search for a recipient by clicking Search, and then select one of the search results. By default, the Search results list displays the five devices most recently registered for your connected app.

a. To find other devices, enter a user name in the Search text box.

b. Click **Go** to generate a list of all devices currently registered under that user name.

2. Optionally, for Alert, enter an alert message or dictionary per Apple’s specifications.
3. For Badge, enter a badge number or 0 for no badge.
4. For Sound, enter the name of a sound file in the application bundle, or enter default to use the system default alert sound.
5. Optionally, to use a custom payload, enter your payload’s JSON value in the Custom Payload field.
6. Click **Send** to send the test push notification, or click **Clear** to reset the form.

For more information, check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361298/how-to-test-push-notification-is-working-in-my-application) and this [thread](http://www.techstricks.com/test-gcm-and-apns-push-notifications-online/) if it can help you.

Comment: it is not jys for testing purpose, I want to pass the token state invalid